# How to find groups of adjacent true values in binary tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recursion, indexing, grouping

I just started with `TensorFlow` (1.13) and I have run in an issue. I have got a 3D binary tensor coming out of a neural network. In this tensor there are 'groups' of true values. This is where adjacent indexes in the binary tensor have true values. I want to extract multiple groups where each group stores indexes where true values are adjacent.

For example a 2D case (resulting in two groups):

```
[[ 0 1 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 0 1 ]
 [ 0 1 1 1 0 ]]
```

I am aiming for the following output:

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1]],
 [[3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]]
```

I require this to determine centers of the true valued adjacent groups, thus something like the following is the ultimate goal:

```
[[0.33, 1.33],
 [3.75, 2.5]]
```

I have tried creating edges between nodes that are within a certain distance. Which gives me the adjacent indexes for a given true value. For the true value at `[0, 1]` this results in `[0, 2]` and `[1, 1]`. I have a list with all these edges but am not able to group these accordingly for the aimed output.

Something like k-means clustering could work, but for that I need to know the amount of true valued groups, which is unknown.

Here is the `numpy` implementation of the collection of adjacent indexes into groups.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [0, 4],
    [1, 4],
    [1, 20],
    [3, 6],
    [6, 9],
    [9, 12],
    [5, 7],
])

# Goal [[0, 1, 4], [3, 6, 9, 12], [5, 7]]

group = []

def search(value, arr):

    nodes, = np.where(arr[:, 0] == value[-1])
    res = arr[nodes]

    if res.size != 0:
        sequence = np.concatenate((value, res), axis=None)
        sequence = np.unique(sequence)
        val = search(sequence, llist)

    return val


while True:

    # search iteratively:
    arr = np.reshape(arr, (-1, 2))
    next_node = search(arr[0], arr)

    group.append(next_node)

    # prevent searches to be restarted and give half results: remove them from array
    mask = np.isin(arr, next_node, invert=True)
    arr = arr[mask]
    if arr.size == 0:
        break

print(group)
```

I am not able to rewrite this to working tensorflow code, although I am not even sure how to properly tackle the problem now. I have broken my head a couple of times now in the past week and hope that you are able to help me. Thanks for consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was some work, but I managed to implement a basic flooding algorithm with a couple of [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). The idea is simple, just take an element, find neighboring elements, then do the same for those until there are no more, and you call that a cluster, then continue with another unassigned element, and so on until you don't have any more elements. Since tensors need to have compact shapes, instead of using something like a [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) I simply format the output as two tensors, one with the coordinates and another one with the index of the cluster to which is belongs (you can probably change the format from there if you want). The code is most definitely not going to be fast, TensorFlow loops usually are not, and the algorithm makes a quadratic comparison on each innermost iteration, but at least it should give you an answer.

Anyway here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def find_clusters(arr):
    # Find coordinates of ones
    coords = tf.where(tf.dtypes.cast(arr, tf.bool))
    s = tf.shape(coords)
    d = coords.shape[1]
    cluster_idx = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 0, element_shape=[None],
                                 dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
    cluster_coords = tf.TensorArray(coords.dtype, 0, element_shape=[None, d],
                                    dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
    i = tf.constant(0, tf.int32)
    i_step = tf.constant(0, tf.int32)
    _, _, _, cluster_idx, cluster_coords = tf.while_loop(
        # While there are unassigned coordinates
        lambda i, i_step, coords, cluster_idx, cluster_coords: tf.shape(coords)[0] > 0,
        # Find new cluster
        next_cluster,
        [i, i_step, coords, cluster_idx, cluster_coords],
        parallel_iterations=1,
        shape_invariants=[i.shape, i_step.shape, tf.TensorShape([None, d]),
                          tf.TensorShape(None), tf.TensorShape(None)])
    return cluster_idx.concat(), cluster_coords.concat()

def next_cluster(i, i_step, coords, cluster_idx, cluster_coords):
    current = coords[:1]
    coords = coords[1:]
    cluster_idx = cluster_idx.write(i_step, [i])
    cluster_coords = cluster_coords.write(i_step, current)
    i_step += 1
    s = tf.TensorShape([None, coords.shape[1]])
    i, i_step, coords, _, cluster_idx, cluster_coords = tf.while_loop(
        # While new elements are added to the cluster
        (lambda i, i_step, coords, current, cluster_idx, cluster_coords:
             tf.not_equal(tf.shape(current)[0], 0)),
        # Find new neighbors
        find_neighbors,
        [i, i_step, coords, current, cluster_idx, cluster_coords],
        parallel_iterations=1,
        shape_invariants=[i.shape, i_step.shape, s, s,
                          tf.TensorShape(None), tf.TensorShape(None)])
    return i + 1, i_step, coords, cluster_idx, cluster_coords

def find_neighbors(i, i_step, coords, current, cluster_idx, cluster_coords):
    # Find coordinates at distance exactly one of previous coordinates
    dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.expand_dims(current, 1) - coords), axis=-1)
    is_close = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(dist, 1), axis=0)
    # Split between neighbors and the rest
    coords, current = tf.dynamic_partition(coords, tf.dtypes.cast(is_close, tf.int32), 2)
    # Write newly found cluster coordinates
    cluster_idx = cluster_idx.write(i_step, tf.fill([tf.shape(current)[0]], i))
    cluster_coords = cluster_coords.write(i_step, current)
    i_step += 1
    return i, i_step, coords, current, cluster_idx, cluster_coords

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    data = tf.constant([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
    cluster_idx, cluster_coords = find_clusters(data)
    for cluster, coord in zip(*sess.run((cluster_idx, cluster_coords))):
        print(f'{coord}: cluster {cluster}')
```

Output:

```
[0 1]: cluster 0
[0 2]: cluster 0
[1 1]: cluster 0
[3 4]: cluster 1
[4 1]: cluster 2
[4 2]: cluster 2
[4 3]: cluster 2
```

EDIT:

If you do want the output as a ragged tensor, here is a simple function to convert the previous format into that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def clusters_to_ragged(cluster_idx, cluster_coords):
    d = cluster_idx[1:] - cluster_idx[:-1]
    s = tf.where(d > 0)[:, 0] + 1
    starts = tf.concat([[0], s], axis=0)
    limits = tf.concat([s, [tf.shape(d)[0] + 1]], axis=0)
    r = tf.ragged.range(starts, limits)
    return tf.gather(cluster_coords, r)

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # Result in previous format
    cluster_idx = tf.constant([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
    cluster_coords = tf.constant([[0, 1],
                                  [0, 2],
                                  [1, 1],
                                  [3, 4],
                                  [4, 1],
                                  [4, 2],
                                  [4, 3]])
    ragged = clusters_to_ragged(cluster_idx, cluster_coords)
    print(*sess.run(ragged).to_list(), sep='\n')
    # [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1]]
    # [[3, 4]]
    # [[4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your super fast answer. I am going to delve into this as I wasn't aware of Ragged Tensors. Small note, If I would want to add the value at [3 4] to be added to what is now cluster 2, I'd reckon I'd have to change the second line in find_neighbors() to  `is_close = tf.reduce_any(tf.less(dist, 1.5), axis=0)` where the 1.5 is the Eucledian distance filtering sqrt(2).

Comment: I have edited the first two lines in `find_neighbors()` to enable a circular search to increase the reach of adjacency. Basically inclusing the true values on the orders of an coordinate. Done by substituting the following lines in there:
`dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(tf.expand_dims(current, 1) - coords), axis=-1)
is_close = tf.reduce_any(tf.less(tf.cast(dist, dtype=tf.float32), 1.5), axis=0)`

this outputs the follwing:
`[0 1]: cluster 0
[0 2]: cluster 0
[1 1]: cluster 0
[2 3]: cluster 1
[3 4]: cluster 1
[4 3]: cluster 1
[4 2]: cluster 1
[4 1]: cluster 1
`

Comment: @Knurft If you want to find immediate neighbors including diagonals, you could do `dist = tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(tf.expand_dims(current, 1) - coords), axis=-1)` (`reduce_max` instead of `reduce_sum`). If you want to search in circular(-ish) neighborhoods, you could either use some custom formula (e.g. either differences add up to 2 or less or maximum difference is 1), or square as you are doing, in which case you could also use [`tf.math.squared_difference`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/squared_difference) if you prefer.

Comment: @Knurft Also added how to convert my initial output to a ragged tensor.

Comment: @jdehese thanks for your answer. It works like a charm. I have found an issue in the ragged tensor generation. For the input: `data = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                            [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])` I get the output for ragged tensor that is `[[0, 0]]
[[0, 4]]
[[3, 4], [4, 4]]
[]` Thus the last cluster is empty, `no [4 0]`. The `cluster_idx` and `cluster_coords` values are correct: `[0 0]: cluster 0
[0 4]: 1
[3 4]: 2
[4 4]: 2
[4 0]: 3`

Comment: @Knurft Right, fixed that now, there was a missing `+ 1` in `clusters_to_ragged`.